# I want to be able to die, but I can't. How do I die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have infinite health (due to hacking with WorldEdit, or possibly TooManyItems, I'm not sure how I did it). This is on an adventure map, so this is not desirable. How can I reverse the effect?

Comment: I swear, the titles you guys come up with over here...

Comment: EPIC Title!!!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After reverting any mods that may be resetting your health, the easiest way would be to drown or sit in lava. Most mods that give you "infinite" health simply set your health to some ridiculously high value so that it is extremely unlikely you will ever run out. Because drowning/sitting in lava constantly damages you, it will require far less effort than repeatedly falling.

Alternatively, if you still have WorldEdit loaded, you could build a tower up to layer 128 and carve a hole to bedrock and fall the greatly exaggerated distance. It will probably take several falls to knock off all the extra health you were granted.

Note that either method can be sped up considerably by installing a mod, such as [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-173-single-player-commands-v210-2/), which will allow you to set your health back to a much more reasonable number.

Comment: Yeah I fixed with Single Player Commands: `/health 0`

Comment: Or simply /kill (which produced undesired effects when the command I was really looking for was /killnpc...)

Answer (score -3):

Let some zombies kill you it might take a while

Comment: Erm... No. Infinite *regenerating* health, that is.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Perhaps I'm being daft, but where was that specified?

Comment: Well, infinite is infinite, so does it matter?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Most mods that give you infinite health simply set your health to some ridiculously high value so that it is extremely unlikely you will ever run out.

Comment: @Timtech Close enough. Might take a long while then.

Comment: Yeah. A long while... :P @JeffreyLin