# I've lost my portal home, and I am invincible. How can I leave the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've gone into the Nether and seemed to have lost my portal out of it, I also can't die in lava or by mobs attacking me, I'm appear to be invincible and can't die.

This is Single Player by the way.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your world set to "Creative Mode"?

Comment: The concern in his question seems to indicate otherwise, but I have see this bug before, logging out usually worked for me though :o

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28166/i-want-to-be-able-to-die-but-i-cant-how-do-i-die Let me know if there's something different going on here.

Comment: Did I read wrongly, or are you complaining about invincibility in a single-player game?

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro I think the main problem here is that he sees death as his only way to return to the overworld.

Comment: `/gamemode survival`

Comment: @SF You mean /gamemode 0

Comment: @Timtech: I mean `/gamemode survival`. Minecraft supports the names (`creative`, `survival`, `adventure`) for as values for /gamemode for quite a while now.

Answer (score 15):

It seems you are playing in creative mode, so you can easily make a new portal to go back to the overworld. If you don't want to, remember you can always double tap space to fly; that should make your hunt easier.

Even if you aren't, *if you created your portal at spawn*, the nether end of it should be in the *general neighbourhood* of X: 0 and Z: 0 (mostly within a 100 meters range of that). Press F3 to show your coordinates and try to head in a direction that brings both X and Z close to zero (Y is your altitude, confusingly). Keep in mind your portal might be high up enough that you can't see it.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are in creative mode, then you are invincible. Can't you build a new portal?

If not; try to kill yourself by digging to the void, or below yourself...

Comment: This is the method that I've used before.

Comment: Falling into the void will kill you even if you are in creative mode.

Comment: You mean falling below bedrock in creative mode if you are in the overworld? I remember trying that but I never died.

Answer (score 2):

You Can:

-make yourself a new portal

-dig down (thanks Zephlon) to the void and die

-use the `/kill` command to die (works like regular dying)

-use the `/gamemode s` command and then jump into the lava

Comment: Digging up into the "void" of the Nether doesn't hurt anymore than flying above y=255 in the overworld. You can, however, dig *down* to the void and die.

Comment: ok, ill fix that