# Lost in the nether in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please could someone give me some advice.  My son has been playing on Minecraft in creative mode.  He has spent hours building a world and today built a portal to the Nether.  He is completely lost and cant find his portal. He seems to be underground.

My question is how can he get back to his much loved world?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also relevant: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123644/help-i-got-lost-in-nether

Answer (score 3):

Type `/kill` in the console, you'll be transported back to your spawn (or the last bed you slept in) in the overworld. You'll lose you inventory, but probably not an issue in creative.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, especially since you're in creative mode.

Just make a portal inside the nether.  It'll take you to the nearest overworld portal or at least out of the nether.

Compasses also help.  If I recall correctly, compasses don't work inside of the nether (They just spin around Bermuda Triangle style) so once you build a portal out of the nether, spawn yourself a compass and find your spawn point.

I would also suggest, especially since it's creative mode, using torches or something similar to navigate your path wherever you go in the nether to always lead back to the portal

Comment: Thanks - Will the spawn point be the world that he has built?

Comment: Wherever he spawned in the overworld is where the compass will point.  If he's used a bed it'll point to that.  And if you're asking about the portal taking him back, yes.  It will not create a new world for him - it'll take him back to whatever world he was in before going to the nether.

Comment: @Mkalafut A bed won't change where the compass points. It always points to the original spawn. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Compass

Comment: Apologies.  Back when I used to play every day it used to point to the original spawn point, or if you used a bed it'll point you there.

Comment: @Mkalafut no apologies needed, I didn't know it used to do that TBH. I wish it still did though!