# Lost in Creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on creative and was exploring the Nether. I happened to travel very far without realizing it and could not find my way back. I decided to try and make another nether portal but that sent me to the middle of an ocean.

I can't kill myself and go to spawn because I am on creative if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Build a compass, it should point to your spawn point.

Comment: Or just give yourself a compass from the creative inventory!

Comment: @Zoredache maybe post that as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've lost my portal home. How can I leave the nether without suiciding?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33601/ive-lost-my-portal-home-how-can-i-leave-the-nether-without-suiciding)

Comment: @Jupotter the title's misleading, he's out of the nether and wants to find spawn

Answer (score 25):

Since you're in creative you can give yourself a [compass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass) and fly to your spawn point (which the compass always points to). Don't try and make your way back via The Nether as your compass won't work there; unfortunately this means you're in for a much longer trip than you went through the nether, but it should be a straight-shot, due to flying.

Unlike digging straight down to the Void (which will work and kill you even in Creative) you won't have to make an ugly hole to the center of the earth, if you care about that.

Answer (score 17):

You can kill yourself in creative: dig straight down and fall in to the void. You will die and respawn at the spawn point.

Answer (score 13):

Push F3, and travel in a direction that puts your X and Z coordinates towards 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can kill yourself with the `/kill` command, but you must have at least snapshot `12w24a`. With `12w25a` you can teleport yourself with `/tp 0 0 0`. Or simply fall into the void - this works in every version.