# How can I go back to the overworld when playing in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Help - my 7 year old has built a world in minecraft and has gone through a nether portal and cannot find her world again? I'm no gamer that's for sure and I simply can't help her she is distraught - Is there anyway we can get her back from where she is stuck?

Comment: If she's okay with losing her inventory she can simply jump in the lava. :)

Comment: She is only on creative and she tells me she can't do that unless she is in survival ?

Comment: If she has cheats enabled, she can just type `/gamemode 1` and the jump in java.

Comment: Then we already have plenty of answers for you :) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74597/lost-in-creative-mode http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33601/ive-lost-my-portal-home-and-i-am-invincible-how-can-i-leave-the-nether?lq=1

Comment: @aman207 Don't you mean `/gamemode 0`...?

Comment: @Atutouato Ah yes you are correct

Answer (score 4):

This is assuming she has cheats enabled.  If cheats are not enabled, go to the pause screen in the world, and click open to LAN.  Then turn cheats on inside that menu.  Then click the button to the lower left of that screen (it should say something like "Open to LAN" or "Post", but I'm not sure).

Now that she has cheats enabled, type "/gamerule keepInventory true" and "/kill" in that exact order, without the quotes, in the chat window.  You can open it using T.

These commands will kill the player (sorry) but they will bring it back to its spawn point in the Overworld, hopefully close to where her creations are.  It's basically the equivalent of jumping into lava in creative mode.